# Does majordomo support 'no mail delivery subscription'?

Tags: email

Mailman, mlmmj and probably other Mailinglist-Software support the feature 'no mail delivery subscription'.

Meaning that you can subscribe and then disable mail delivery.

This useful for times you are at vacation or when you want to read that list via gmane.org or a similar service.

I can't find anything about majordomo, regarding this feature.

Thus my question: Does majordomo support 'no mail delivery subscription'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Majardomo  seems to be pretty much end of development, and via internet search one find just rumours that a future development majordomo version would support such a feature ... perhaps.

Anyway, most mailing-lists seem to have switched from majordomo - currently, one famous exception is the Postfix mailing list.